# Why does this code write a "corrupt file" that Word cannot open (not even "Open and Repair")?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I'm a newb, feel free talk down to me.
Sorry to be so vague; the code executes and writes a corrupt file. I can't get into the corrupt file to observe any errors/anomolies.  The size does look like a sum of the files being merged.

I've googled the snot outta this and can't find anything I can understand how to implement.

The Word error on open is:
The file cannot be open because there are problems with the contents

and

Word found unreadable content, do you want to continue?

When I click Yes I get the first error again & then I'm out.

THe documents have content controls with the same name, but I've modded this to only add 1 doc in an effort to see if dupe content types would be a problem; same corrupt file results.

btw....my ultimate intent is to overwrite the "template" (...Aggregate Report.dotx) in place.  But I can't get a valid file saved ANYWHERE, so...... :-/

```
using System;   
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using Word = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;


namespace BobsDocMerger.VisualWebPart1
{
[ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
public class VisualWebPart1 : WebPart
{
    // Visual Studio might automatically update this path when you change the Visual Web Part project item.
    private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/BobsDocMerger/VisualWebPart1/VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx";

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        System.Web.UI.Control control = this.Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
        Controls.Add(control);
        base.CreateChildControls();
        Button btnSubmit = new Button();
        btnSubmit.Text = "Assemble Documents";
        btnSubmit.Click += new EventHandler(btnSubmit_Click);
        Controls.Add(btnSubmit);
    }

    void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPFolder folder = SPContext.Current.ListItem.Folder;
        char[] splitter = { '/' };
        string[] folderName = folder.Name.Split(splitter);
        string filePrefix = @"Weekly/" + folderName[0] + "/" + folderName[0];

        SPFile template = folder.Files[filePrefix + " - Aggregate Report.dotx"];
        SPFile file;
        byte[] byteArray = template.OpenBinary();

        using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            mem.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);

            using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, true))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
                //Loop thru content controls
                foreach (Word.SdtElement sdt in mainPart.Document.Descendants<Word.SdtElement>().ToList())
                {
                    Word.SdtAlias alias = sdt.Descendants<Word.SdtAlias>().FirstOrDefault();
                    if (alias != null)
                    {
                        //The 2 tags in the Report are AggregateHeader and AggregateBody
                        string sdtTitle = alias.Val.Value;
                        string sdtTag = sdt.GetFirstChild<SdtProperties>().GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val;
                        if (sdtTitle == "Merge")
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < folder.Files.Count; i++)
                            {
                                file = folder.Files[i];
                                //Do all files that are NOT the Aggregate Report
                                if (file.Name.IndexOf("Aggregate Report") == -1)
                                {
                                    if (i == folder.Files.Count-1)
                                    {
                                        AddAltChunk(mainPart, sdt, file, true);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        AddAltChunk(mainPart, sdt, file, false);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                HttpResponse resp = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                resp.ClearContent();
                resp.ClearHeaders();
                resp.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Assembled Document.docx");
                //resp.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                resp.ContentType = "application/msword";
                resp.OutputStream.Write(mem.ToArray(), 0, (int)mem.Length);
                resp.Flush();
                resp.Close();
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            }
        }
    }

    protected int id = 1;

    void AddAltChunk(MainDocumentPart mainPart, Word.SdtElement sdt, SPFile filename,bool LastPass)
    {
        string altChunkId = "AltChunkId" + id;
        id++;
        byte[] byteArray = filename.OpenBinary();

        AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
        AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);

        using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            mem.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
            mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            chunk.FeedData(mem);
        }

        Word.AltChunk altChunk = new Word.AltChunk();
        altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
        //Replace content control with altChunk information 

        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement parent = sdt.Parent;
        parent.InsertBefore(altChunk, sdt);
        if (LastPass) { sdt.Remove(); }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Heh....easier to find my stuff in the morass of nonsense. :)

Comment: I notice you `.Open()` a stream you wrote from a "binary" file read.  Why don't you start by using the version of `WordprocessingDocument.Open()` that takes in a file name and reads the file directly?

Comment: @ebyrob Well, I assume that's this: byte[] byteArray = template.OpenBinary(); using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream()) { mem.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length); using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, true)) I ...ah...being a newb....can't figure out how to do what you said; lil help?

Comment: @jazaddict well you'd need a string file name...  Are you somewhere you don't actually have physical file paths?  An alternative might be removing all your merge logic and seeing if you can emit the template unchanged correctly.

Comment: oops....I can't  believe I didn't mention that this is a sharepoint site.   So THATS why all the "document in memory" nonsense.   From MSDN "Working with Open XML Documents without loading from a file or saving to a file is important when you build applications that work with Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 or Microsoft ASP.NET Web applications"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not calling `.Seek()` properly on the main memory stream, also you seem to be using that single memory stream for both input and output possibly at the same time.  (Maybe it's correct, but it's just very confusing to me when it's mixed mode)

I'm assuming you can't access raw filenames and the filesystem:

```
using(Stream t = template.OpenBinaryStream())
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(t, true))
    {
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(resp.OutputStream))
        {
            // TODO re-add merge logic here once it works

            HttpResponse resp = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            resp.ClearContent();
            resp.ClearHeaders();
            resp.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                "attachment; filename=Assembled Document.docx");
            //resp.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            resp.ContentType = "application/msword";
            // resp.OutputStream.Write(mem.ToArray(), 0, (int)mem.Length);
/* new */   myDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.WriteTo(writer);
            resp.Flush();
            resp.Close();
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

PS - I recommend getting a raw template to output correctly first.  Then make one tiny change and see that output before re-adding your merge logic.

Comment: Aight....I have clues: PART of the problem was that the type of doc I was opening was a TEMPLATE (dotx), but the type I was saving was a DOCUMENT (docx).  I changed the opening doc to docx. So now the corruption STILL EXISTS (???) but Open-Repair works.

Comment: However, none of teh altchunk data gets written, and the removal of the content control (sdt) on the last pass executes, but doesn't atually remove it. WHat I get in the result file is an unchanged copy of the original template (that's no longer a template, but now a docx)....ugh.  THis might be the "not calling .Seek() properly???

Comment: More clues: parent.InnerText.Length 164 Then Parent.InsertBefore(altchunk,sdt); then parent.InnerText.Length 164, so NO data in altchunk !?! ....I verified mem.length is 0 then larger after mem.write, but I can't find the size or length of chunk to verify chunk.feeddata is putting anything into chunk (appears not) .... :/

Comment: @jazaddict Actually, if you're generating an unmodified template now, then you probably have what I was worried about figured out.  Did you try using `.WriteTo()` or did you stick with some kind of autoupdate with a single stream?  (Not saying you should use `.WriteTo()` for production, but it might help with diagnosis)